# Golden Calf connected to Purim?

Tags: purim, golden-calf-egel

Shemos 32:31
וַיָּשׇׁב מֹשֶׁה אֶל־יְהֹוָה וַיֹּאמַר אָנָּא חָטָא הָעָם הַזֶּה חֲטָאָה גְדֹלָה וַיַּעֲשׂוּ לָהֶם אֱלֹהֵי זָהָב

"Moshe returned to Adonoy and said, “I beseech You! This people have committed a great sin and have made a god of gold."

Rashi explains that the inference of "gold" was an excuse that the jewish people had an abundance of gold (from the egyptians) and thus were compelled to use it.

Is there a known connection made to the fact that in the story of purim, although the jews had the ability to collect the spoils from their enemies they chose not to. Can this be related to the golden calf?

Comment: I once heard a shiur connecting the 10,000 talents of silver promised by Haman to the weight of the Golden Calf, but I don't recall the details.

Comment: @N.T. interesting, thanks!